# Schedule a .bat file to run at a certain time/within a certain amount of minutes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks, cmd.exe

How do you schedule a task to run a batch file at a certain time/within a certain amount of minutes? I'd use `at 12:34 C:\example.bat` but unfortunately the AT command is deprecated..
I'd like to use it so that my hotspot disables after e.g. 30 minutes or at midnight.
The .bat file executes this amongst others: `netsh wlan disable hostednetwork`.
I believe it is not possible to schedule a single command line is it?
In that case that would be even better.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. The last command you list can be scheduled using the answer given by @LPChip. In the scheduler, add an action put `netsh` in the command and the parameters in the arguments field. You might need to work out what folder `netsh` is in.

Comment: I had a question that asked this and got some pretty good answers, but it's apparently been deleted.  But Task Scheduler is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Just schedule it using Control Panel->Administrative tools->Task Scheduler.

It has all the options you need.

Also, if it is just one command in the .bat file, you can schedule just this task using Task Scheduler. Enter netsh as program and wlan disable hostednetwork as its parameters.

Comment: thanks but yes i know that and i've tried that to see if it works(it does). But i need a command line which does it.

Comment: You can start or create scheduled tasks from the commandline as well using `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe` `/Run` or `/Create`. See `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /?` for more info.

Comment: okay thanks! so how would you create the command which executes example.bat after 30 minutes? or at 12:00 hours?

Comment: @Bart - Study the Task Scheduler options -- you can have the command execute at a given time, after a given delay, repeat with a given frequency, etc.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to interpret that syntax properly i'm just playing around with batch programming. i've already got two entire days of experience :P

Comment: in addition to that, is it possible to schedule a task which is triggered when wifi turns on/connects?

Comment: Task Scheduler is not writing a bat file. It is a program which does what you expect it to do, it has a User Interface to make tasks based on predefined triggers, such as: at a specific time of the day, or basic computer events such as: at logon, at workstation lock/unlock etc. You can't start a task if you have a connection with wifi. I bet there are other programs that can do this, but that would exceed the scope of your current question or even SuperUser for that matter. So I suggest to open `Task Scheduler` and just create a basic task and see what the options are. It really makes sense.

Comment: thanks but i can manually create a task that runs a batch file when my wifi connects so i thought it was possible to create such a task with a cmd command, too.